# How to invoke a function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, web3-providers, command-line

I have a function as follows :

```
/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
  /// @notice send `Pl_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
  /// @param _to The address of the recipient
  /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
  /// @param Pl_value The payload to be transferred
  /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
  function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, string Pl_value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);

    Payload[_to] = Pl_value;

    return true;
  }

}
```

And I create an instance from my contract as follows :

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, 'address-of-contract');
```

How can I call this function via :

```
contractInstance.methods.
```

What is its syntax exactly ?
(I do it via command prompt and terminal)

Here is the entire .sol file :

```
import './SafeMath.sol';

contract BasicToken {

  // Using safe math library for all uint256 operations
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // Total supply of token
  uint256 public totalSupply;

  // Balances for each account
  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  mapping(address => string) Payload;

  /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
  /// @return The balance
  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

  /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
  /// @return The payload
  function PayloadOf(address _owner) constant returns (string payload) {
    return Payload[_owner];
  }

  /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
  /// @notice send `Pl_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
  /// @param _to The address of the recipient
  /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
  /// @param Pl_value The payload to be transferred
  /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
  function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, string Pl_value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);

    Payload[_to] = Pl_value;

    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using web3.js 1.0, you call it like this:

```
contractInstance.methods.transfer(<method parameters>).send(<options>)
```

where  are the parameters of the transfer method: `_from`, `_to`, `_value` and `Pl_value`. With  you can specify the transaction options, like he address the transaction should be sent from or the gas price. See documentation: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

Comment: Thank you. I added entire .sol file in the question. If I need to add some thing else, please let me know.

Comment: This command format is correct for this function? contract_Instance.methods.transfer('from_address', 'to_address', 'value_int', 'Pl_value_string').send({ from: 'contract_account_address' }, function(error, result)

Comment: `from` should be the account who is going to call the smart contract.

Comment: If you mean "send({ from: 'contract_account_address' } ..." from is the account which deployed the contract. So, is it correct? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have to be. It can be any account. Also keep in mind that a smart contract cannot 'send' a transaction. See this: http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html#eoa-vs-contract-accounts

Comment: I sent several times some transactions via a consortium established on ethereum, but none of are mined or confirmed Do you know what might be the reason ?